# How to call periods for which a decision has been made?

Tags: word-choice

Scenario

A clerk reviews one's case regarding a temporary treatment or reimbursement (say welfare or treatment). Then, they make a decision to extend said period (by three to six months). After that, a new review is scheduled. This process can continue for years, sometimes even the rest of one's (working) life. Officially, the aim is to get a subject up and running but that's usually not the case, regrettably.

In order to provide statistics over such extensions, we have introduced a term *period*. However, "*her period will last forever*" or "*when will the period end*" sounds, well... you get the point.

So we called them *decision periods*.

Is there a better way to refer to such entities? It's supposed to sound dry, bureaucratic and official.

Comment: I don't think English is likely to have a specific term for ***separate consecutive extension [periods/decisions]***, as appears to be requested here. We'd more likely just "collapse" them all into a single "contiguous" period *(Her [temporary/interim/etc] **status** will last forever)*, or focus on the periodic interim decisions as separate  "events" *(Her **reviews** will go on forever)*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I have but one remark: what you wrote feels to me more as a possible answer (especially given the examples) than a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in comments:

> I don't think English is likely to have a specific term for **separate consecutive extension [periods/decisions]**, as appears to be requested here. We'd more likely just "collapse" them all into a single "contiguous" period (Her [temporary/interim/etc] **status** will last forever), or focus on the periodic interim decisions as separate "events" (Her **reviews** will go on forever). –  [FumbleFingers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/126/fumblefingers) [Mar 24 2015](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/53486/how-to-call-periods-for-which-a-decision-has-been-made#comment100331_53486)